# Flutter Delete Getx Controller through variable

Tags: flutter, controller, put, flutter-getx

I need to remove and put `GetxController` to run all its default function like `onInit`, `onReady` .

This work fine with `Get.delete<MyHomeController>();`

I need this command with variable reference like

```
String myControllerName = 'MyHomeController';
Get.delete< myControllerName>();
```

Can I do something like this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This function cannot set a string in  as you can see in the structure below

```
Future<bool> delete<S>({String? tag, bool force = false})
```

Comment: Ok. Is there any function in flutter like macro which by I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's easier way to do it, but one option is just to make a helper method that lists all controllers you have, something like this:

```
  void delete(String s) {
    switch (s) {
      case 'MyHomeController':
        Get.delete<MyHomeController>();
        break;
      case 'AnotherController':
        Get.delete<AnotherController>();
        break;
      case 'ThirdController':
        Get.delete<ThirdController>();
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ok. I'm avoiding writing all controller delete. Any method where I don't have to write all controller.